# POE 802.3at hardware vs LLDP negotiation

Tags: power-over-ethernet, lldp

I have tested a 802.3at switch (POE PSE) that gives the PD device 25.5W through hardware negotiation.

After the PD device boots, it checks the LLDP POE fields and sees this:
[image]

So, the switch reports itself as a PSE device, and it shows that the PD has requested 25.5W through LLDP, however, it claims that it has given the PD nothing (0.0W), which is clearly not correct, since the PD device has been able to boot.

This behavior continues at least for minutes.

I know LLDP is optional on the PSE side, but I would have thought that if the PSE implements the LLDP fields needed for power negotiation it should also support it.

To me this seems like an error on the PSE/switch side.

What do others think?

Comment: That's not really how it's defined, but may be common for a low-cost endspan that doesn't track power usage - what type/model is that switch? Latest firmware?

Comment: I will check the brand and version but haven't yet. I do wish the standard gave us more rules and recommendations to make it easier to design devices and switches that work well (and the same way) together regardless of brands.

Comment: The device was made by Rubytech. I'll check if I can find a newer firmware

Comment: I'd really contact their support and ask them. Btw, Rubytech seems to resell/rebrand MikroTik gear - the Rubytech GSH-5POE resembles the MikroTik RB260GSP for instance.